# Using `Objects.equals()` in Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use the `Objects.equals(obj a, obj b)` method ([link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html)) in Android, but it seems Android does not have access to it. As far as I'm aware, this class was available in Java 1.7 and later. Is there any way to have access to this class in Android? Or is there an equivalent method that behaves the same way that I can use instead?

Comment: There is no reason you cannot access it. Object class is the base of java objects. By the way it is referenced in the doc http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object.html       What are you trying to do ?

Comment: The current versions of Android are compatible with Java 6, not Java 7, so methods that were added in Java 7 or later are not available.

Comment: @Mr.Starck Note that Teifi is talking about `Objects`, not `Object`. This is a new class with utility methods that was added in Java 7.

Comment: My apologize, I have read too quick. Thanks Jesper ;)

Comment: Thanks @Jesper. Looks like I'll just have to write my own utilities class that will behave the same way as `Objects.equals()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The javadoc for `Objects.equals(obj a, obj b)` says:
Returns true if the arguments are equal to each other and false otherwise. Consequently, if both arguments are null, true is returned and if exactly one argument is null, false is returned. Otherwise, equality is determined by using the equals method of the first argument.

which is the equivalent to:

> ```
> if (a == null && b == null) {
>    return true; 
> } else if (a == null || b == null) {
>    return false; 
> } else return a.equals(b);
> ```

Comment: Based on OP's requirements, this is the correct answer.

Comment: you can also do a == null ^ b == null

Answer (score 9):

`Objects.equals()` has the following source:

```
public static boolean equals(Object a, Object b) {
     return (a == b) || (a != null && a.equals(b));
 }
```

Comment: I need a method that will compare two objects regardless of their `null` or `not null` status.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `equals()` *on* an `Object`:

```
if(object1.equals(object2)){ 
    // Do something 
}
```

Comment: This does not behave the same way as `Objects.equals(obj a, obj b)`. `Object.equals(obj a)` does not handle `null` so I can't use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use java 7 with compile level 19 (without try-resources if below min-level 19). You can change the compile-Options with gradle by setting the compileOptions:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

Here is a full example:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 16
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `StringValue.equals(Object o);` It may help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the compat class [ObjectsCompat.equals](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/ObjectsCompat) which is supported from v4.

Answer (score 0):

If You can use Apache objectutils

`ObjectUtils.equals(Object object1, Object object2)` -- Returns boolean

Compares two objects for equality, where either one or both objects may be null.

```
 ObjectUtils.equals(null, null)                  = true
 ObjectUtils.equals(null, "")                    = false
 ObjectUtils.equals("", null)                    = false
 ObjectUtils.equals("", "")                      = true
 ObjectUtils.equals(Boolean.TRUE, null)          = false
 ObjectUtils.equals(Boolean.TRUE, "true")        = false
 ObjectUtils.equals(Boolean.TRUE, Boolean.TRUE)  = true
 ObjectUtils.equals(Boolean.TRUE, Boolean.FALSE) = false
```

Comment: Don't have access to this class in Android, so I think this may be a Java 1.7 addition too.

Comment: No You have to add [commons-lang-2.5.jar](http://mavenhub.com/c/org/apache/commons/lang/objectutils/jar) in your classpath